# Play! Framework's WS functions seem to be dropping my GET variables

Tags: http, scala, playframework

I'm pretty new to the Play! Framework (and Scala itself, really), but I seem to have hit the wall on implementing a (common?) function. My code is as follows:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.libs._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {
     def jsonStringMap(str: String) =
      util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(str) match {
         case Some(m: Map[_,_]) => m collect {
               // If this doesn't match, we'll just ignore the value
               case (k: String, v: String) => (k,v)
            } toMap
         case _ => Map[String,String]()
      }

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."));
  }

  def view_mix(id: Int) = Action {
    Ok("")
  }

  def view_popular = Action {
    val whydoyouhateme: F.Promise[play.libs.WS.Response] = WS.url("http://8tracks.com/mixes/1002?format=json&api_key=10889794345788a1eee1110e06b5aa5405d76170").get()
    Ok(whydoyouhateme.get().getBody())
  }
}
```

The line I care about (val whydoyouhateme....) should, if logic stands to serve, return the same as if I pointed my browser to http://8tracks.com/mixes/1002?format=json&api_key=10889794345788a1eee1110e06b5aa5405d76170. That's unfortunately not the case. It's giving me what I would see if I went to http://8tracks.com/mixes/1002 (which is simply a redirect).

Am I missing something here? Do I have to specify GET variables elsewhere? This is really driving me nuts and the Eclipse IDE isn't doing much in the way of offering assistance (code completion fails me again).

Open to all solutions, I'm comfortable introducing a new library if necessary.

Comment: I don't know how sensitive the API key is, but I recommend obfuscating it when posting.

Comment: It's not sensitive at all in this particular application (I've got literally hundreds, my particular application is strictly violating their ToS so I'm going through them fairly frequently) - but good suggestion. I'll try to adhere to that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

FML! Go figure. I'm missing a rather important specification (setQueryParameter(string, string)).

Fixed line:

```
val whydoyouhateme: F.Promise[play.libs.WS.Response] = WS.url("http://8tracks.com/mixes/1002").setQueryParameter("format", "json").setQueryParameter("api_key", "10889794345788a1eee1110e06b5aa5405d76170").get()
```

Hope somebody else might find this useful.